# Android Java exception even after string null or empty check

Tags: java, android, string, null

I really don't understand why java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null" happens here.

The problem snippet is like followings.

```
try {
        userid = ((JSONObject) msg.obj).getString("userid");
        if (userid.equals("") || userid.isEmpty() || null==userid) {
                onClickLogout();
                return;
        } else {
            client.setUserid(Long.parseLong(userid));
       }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            onClickLogout();
            return;
    }
```

the line client.setUserid(Long.parseLong(userid)); gets following exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:125)
at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:362)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:319)
at client.setUserid(Long.parseLong(userid));
```

The point is that the null exception occurs even after null and empty check of the userid in the code. What's wrong with me here? please check it out experts!

Comment: Check first if the userid is null instead of calling equals otherwise you may run into a NPE

Comment: I've edited your question, please check. This could avoid a possible NullPointerException. In addition, you should add @laalto 'sanswer.

Comment: Oh, sorry @PedroOliveira. I've just seen your comment xD

Comment: Oops, thank you. It was my first edit. I didn't know this. Sorry

Comment: Thanks guys! The strange thing here is that userid = ((JSONObject) msg.obj).getString("userid"); gets only "" or some numbers. "" case covers that there is no related userid number. the null case is sort of impossible case here actually. and this case happens in rare. I've seen this case just through google report. I'll try @laalto 's solution this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string *value* and not reference is `null`.

You can add `"null".equals(userid)` to test for the literal `null` value in the `if` where you check for various forms of "no value".

Comment: Thanks guys! The strange thing here is that userid = ((JSONObject) msg.obj).getString("userid"); gets only "" or some numbers. "" case covers that there is no related userid number. the null case is sort of impossible case here actually. and this case happens in rare. I've seen this case just through google report. I'll try your solution this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Always check first  for null value in your condition

```
if (null==userid || userid.isEmpty() || userid.equals("null") {
```

Then, in the next element of your condition, you are sure that userid is not null and no NullPointerException will be thrown

Also, in your case, check that userid does not contain the "null" String

Moreover `userid.equals("")` and `userid.isEmpty()` are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! laalto stole your thunder!

Answer (score 0):

You can check `null` with utility method `isEmpty` from `TextUtils`,

```
public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
     return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

`isEmpty(CharSequence str)` method check both condition, for `null` and length.